# Ruby on Rails - Add new Controller Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Well I want to be able to add a new method to my UsersController called home.

right now the controller has this

```
  def home
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

I added this on the routes file

```
  match '/user_home', to: 'users#home', via: 'get'
```

and i created the View home.html.erb on the users folder.

I got this error:

Couldn't find User wihtout an ID.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Because this is not what you have asked I'm writing this as a comment as an alternative, and if everything is not working out for you - you can try my solution.
routes.rb: 
resources :users do 
  member do
    get 'user_home', to: "user#home", as: "user_home"
  end
end

users_controller.rb:

def home
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

Answer (score 4):

Alternative approach:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'home'
  end
end
```

This way you will get a route `/users/:id/home`. The `member` keyword achieves ensuring the ID for the actions defined in the block.

You can read more about routing in Rails Guides - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that the path has an 'id' parameter at.

```
match '/user_home/:id', to: 'users#home', via: 'get'
```

You should also add the 'id' parameter to the link you try to visit.

E.g: `localhost/user_home/16`

[Further reading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: then what should I put on my link_to tags and my redirects? i was expecting user_home_path but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It's because the params[:id] value is nil, because you don't send any id of user : Therefore, the "find" method throws an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, because it needs a real id to find the user.

If you don't want your home method to throw an error, you could use the "find_by_id" method instead :

```
def home
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
end
```

But if you want to pass an id (and that should be the case), you should use :

```
match '/user_home/:id', to: 'users#home', via: 'get'
```

Rails will then recognize the "id" part in your URL, and pass it to the params.

Answer (score 0):

Without updating your route to include the `:id`, you would have to use a URL like:

```
/user_home?id=21
```

If you want a custom path helper, something like this:

```
match '/user_home/:id' => 'users#home', via: :get, as: 'user_home'
```

Then you can use:

```
<%= user_home_path(22) %>
```

or

```
<%= user_home_path(id: 23) %>
```

in your views.

Or for a fully qualified path:

```
<%= user_home_url(id: 23) %>
```

Comment: You can still use a path helper for your current route (by defining the 'as:' parameter in the route definition), if you want to use the querystring. Just use the second form in the view.